# R Shiny: Is there any way to read a single backslash in user input?

Tags: r, bash, shiny, double-quotes, backslash

I'm making a Shiny app that constructs a bash script to run on a cluster (basically just a txt file). One of the user inputs is a curl command (provided by the database where the files are stored) that they can copy/paste into a textInput field in the app. When run on the cluster, it will download the file for further processing. However, the curl command they provide contains several single backslashes. Example:

```
curl --cookie jgi_session=/api/sessions/ec32f2d578304a9e62b4646ae2bec6d4 --output download.20210731.211924.zip -d "{\"ids\":[\"5d94dc9fc0d65a87debccfd3\"]}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://files.jgi.doe.gov/filedownload/
```

It works fine if I paste this directly into a script or if I manually add in double backslashes, but I want to keep this as user friendly as possible. Every other post I've seen about this just says to use double backslashes, but I'd rather do this automatically if at all possible. So any ideas? I'm open to alternate solutions, less work for the user the better.

Comment: In R "\\" is a single backslash. Try it. At a console session enter: `nchar("\\")` and after seeing `1`, type: `cat("\\")`. Furthermore what's being done there is to escape the double quotes, so there are no backslashes in that string, just escaped double quotes inside a string that is double-quoted. You should read up on quoting in bash.

Comment: Would it help to switch the outer quotes on that parameter to single-quotes, so the inner ones don't have to be escaped with backslashes? That is, use `... -d '{"ids":["5d94dc9fc0d65a87debccfd3"]}' ...`

Comment: Can you provide an example of how the input is processed? When I build a simple textInput and enter `\ ` in the field, the result of `print(input$myTextInput)` is `\\ `. In other words, R shiny provides the conversion for you. Depending on how you generate the output, there may be some conversion from escaped characters. I've had cases (mostly python, though) where I actually had to put `\\\\ ` to end up with a single backslash, because of multiple parsing.

Comment: @All Downhill From Here. Yes, sorry. I am taking the user input and writing it to a txt file using writeLines(). `fileConn <- file("outputs/TEST.txt")` `writeLines(c(curl ...), fileConn)` `close(fileConn)` The output is the string I have above but with the backslashes missing. I tried what you suggested (using print()) and it printed to the console with single backslashes. Is there any way to print directly to a txt file or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is picking up the curl line as escaped characters. When you write to file, those escaped characters get converted to their actual character (i.e `\"` gets converted to literal `"`.

To avoid, replace special escaped characters by the character sequence that literally created the escape sequence. So to build `\"` in the final written string, you have to produce `\\"` as escaped character sequence (which is what the output of a `print` commmand should show).

Once way to achieve this for this particular character sequence is

```
escapedString = gsub('\"', '\\"', curlString)
```

Note that, in terms of string interpretation, `\"` is a single character (converting to `"`), while `\\"` is a sequence of two characters: an escaped `\` and a literal `"`, converting to `\"` when written, which is the desired output.